# How to check duplicate posts when submitting a new post in Django admin?

Tags: django, django-admin

I have coworkers to upload posts through Django admin. The problem is they keep making duplicate posts as we've been covering a lot of posts. Is there a way to find out if a post already exists when typing a certain column or submitting?

I searched about that, but didn't get any useful information.

Comment: You need to clarify what "duplicate" means in your business case. If for example, there is a field containing text and it is considered a duplicate if it another row contains this exact text - in that case the easy solution would be to declare this field as `unique=True` in your model. But in all depends on how you define duplicate in your business.

Comment: `unique=True` is working very well. Thank! By the way, just for curious, is it possible to check out duplicates while typing every single character? I'm asking cuz `unique=True` shows duplicate after clicking the submit button/

Comment: see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your business case seems to be a text that is duplicate if it is case sensitive equal.

On a DB and Django Model level you assure unique entries by adding `unique`:

```
class MyModel(Model):
    my_field = TextField(unique=True)
```

To check during input you need JavaScript in the client and an AJAX endpoint on the Django server side. It's actually an Autocomplete/Autosuggest functionality for that field. There are several packages that might help you with that. Out of the box, the Django Admin does not support this.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know that!